# Get a part of another page

Tags: ajax

I am trying to fetch a part of the page from another domain. I could directly embed as a

frame. But i need to retrieve a part of it. How can i? I use:

```
$.ajax({    

type: "POST",

            url: "marketToday.php",

            data: "symbol=" + symbol,

            success: function(html)

            {
                        alert(html);
            }
         });
```

in marketToday.php:

I retrieve a page using curl

Comment: It's unclear where the problem is here.  Are you receiving the correct data in `html` (as soon in the `alert()`) and you just need to parse out a specific part and display it somewhere?

Comment: i receive the page which i required. i need to get some values by pointing to their 'id' contained in html. What do u mean by parsing out a specific part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has built-in libraries (usually included by default) for DOM manipulation.  Essentially you would need to use curl or `file_get_contents()` and then parse the source code with DOM or XPATH.